# Glossaries and custom section headings broken

Tags: errors, header-footer, glossaries, fancyhdr

I've a document, where I use the `glossaries` package to manage acronyms for me. Sometimes, I use a `\gls{}` command inside a section heading, and I have defined page headers to have the current section heading. However, when a section heading contains a `\gls{}` command, the headings for those pages render incorrectly, with what appears to be some code from the `glossaries` package appearing instead.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[toc,xindy,nonumberlist,acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection #1}{}}
\newacronym{ecg}{ECG}{electrocardiogram}
\chapter{test}
\gls{ecg} is ecg
\pagebreak
\section{\gls{ecg}}
waffle here
\end{document}
```

I should note, I am compiling this with TL2011, but I have also had a friend with TL2013 test it.

Comment: The [user manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glslink) warns against using `\gls` in section headings as does the [glossaries FAQ](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#movingarg) so try replacing `\section{\gls{ecg}}` with `\section{\glsentryshort{ecg}}` (also consider moving `\newacronym` to the preamble).

Comment: Is this not something that can be fixed? It presents quite a big usability hurdle for the whole package which is otherwise excellent. As an aside, I have no known issues when using \gls inside captions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both the [user manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html) and the [`glossaries` FAQ](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries) caution against using commands like `\gls` in chapter or section headings (and also for captions). However, if you're using the extension package [glossaries-extra](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), most of the associated problems can be overcome by using commands like `\glsfmttext`, `\glsfmtshort`, `\glsfmtlong` or `\glsfmtfull` instead of commands like `\gls`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newacronym{sa}{SA}{sample acronym}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\glsfmttext{sample}}

\section{Full: \glsfmtfull{sa}}

\section{Short: \glsfmtshort{sa}}

\section{Long: \glsfmtlong{sa}}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

With just the `glossaries` package, you have to use commands like `\glsentrytext`, `\glsentryshort` or `\glsentrylong`, which don't contain any formatting commands.

The problems with using commands like `\gls` in section headings are as follows:

**1. Documents with a Table of Contents**

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\gls{sample}}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This results in the table of contents page appearing in the location list for the `sample` entry. This isn't what most users expect, and it's not helpful for the reader.

Things get even worse when `hyperref` is added:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\gls{sample}}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The line in the table of contents now has a nested link. The word "sample" is trying to link both to the page where `\chapter` occurs *and* to the definition of "sample" in the glossary. Which one ends up as the actual target? If I use `pdflatex` the link will take me to `\chapter` when I view the document with `okular`, but to the definition in the glossary when I use `evince`. If I use `latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf` the reverse happens.

The PDF bookmarks also fail with this example, and `hyperref` issues the warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\gls' on input line 20.
```

This is because `\gls` is robust and can't be expanded to a simple string, so the command `\gls` is discarded and just the label appears in the bookmark. In this case the label is the same as the text, but this isn't necessarily the case.

Now change the example so that it defines an acronym instead:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{sample acronym}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\gls{sa}}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Here the "first use" occurs in the table of contents, so in the contents `\gls{sa}` is expanded to its full form, but `\chapter{\gls{sa}}` now uses the short form. You can get around this by adding `\glsresetall` after `\tableofcontents` but inconsistencies can occur if the acronym is used after the table of contents but before `\chapter{\gls{sa}}`. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{sample acronym}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\glsresetall

\chapter{Sample}

\gls{sa}

\chapter{\gls{sa}}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Now the table of contents uses the full form but the actual chapter uses the short form. While you can specify an alternative chapter title for the TOC using the optional argument of `\chapter`, this kind of discrepancy looks a bit weird as the optional argument is usually used to provide a shortened version of a long chapter title.

**2. Documents with Headers**

This is the case in your question. One of the changes in `glossaries` v4.10 makes it work a bit better in this case, but there are still instances when it fails.

First consider this example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{sample acronym}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\glsresetall

\chapter{\gls{sa}}

\lipsum[1-20]

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This now works with v4.10, but the headings use the short form as the acronym has already been used, so the headings are inconsistent with the chapter title and the corresponding line in the table of contents. In addition, the location list for this entry is now: 1, 3, 5, 7. The first page is the reference in the table of contents and pages 5 and 7 are caused by the reference in the header. While one author might want to suppress the location list, another might not and may be perplexed as to why the location list has so many entries.

However, even with v4.10 a problem occurs when `\MakeUppercase` is used in the heading (which occurs by default):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{%
 \markboth
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter}}
  {\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\gls{sample}}

\lipsum[1-20]

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

With v4.10, this now causes an error:

```
! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `SAMPLE' has not been defined.
```

This is because `\MakeUppercase` converts the label to upper case within the action of TeX's `\mark` primitive. This issue isn't peculiar to `glossaries` but also occurs in other cases. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}\label{ch:sample}

\lipsum

\chapter{Following on from \ref{ch:sample}}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This results in the warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `CH:SAMPLE' on page 4 undefined on input line 15.
```

and the reference will appear as ??

**Summary**

With just `glossaries` (without `glossaries-extra`), the only way to avoid all these issues is to use one of the *expandable* commands instead of the robust `\gls`. For example `\glsentrytext` for regular entries and one of `\glsentrylong`, `\glsentryshort` or `\glsentryfull` for acronyms. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newacronym{sa}{SA}{sample acronym}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{%
 \markboth
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter}}
  {\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\glsentrytext{sample}}

\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{\glsentryfull{sa}}

\lipsum[21-40]

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This works with `\MakeUppercase` because the expansion is now performed before the case change is applied inside `\mark`. There are also no discrepancies with the chapter title, the header and the table of contents entry and, if used with `hyperref`, this works with the PDF bookmarks and doesn't cause nested links.

If the thing that puts you off using those commands is merely the amount of typing, remember that you can define your own shortcut commands to use instead. For example:

```
\newcommand*{\gtxt}{\glsentrytext}
\newcommand*{\glng}{\glsentrylong}
\newcommand*{\gsht}{\glsentryshort}
```

Alternatively, set up some mappings if your editor provides that facility.

Comment: Thank you very much. One quick question I have (which I couldn't seem to find the answer to in the documentation) - are the acr* commands expandable or not?

Comment: @user1207217 They're not expandable.

Comment: Great answer and great package, @NicolaTalbot! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Is there a recommended method for using pluralized versions of acronyms in section headings?

Comment: Ah, just figured out that I could use `\glsentryshortpl{}`, `Glsentryshort{}` in order to force pluralization, capitalization etc., although these variants don't seem to be mentioned in the official manual.

Comment: @ali_m They're described in the section [Acronyms and Other Abbreviations](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:acronyms) (after the linking commands, such as `\acrfullpl`).

Comment: I now realise that I've been looking in the 'beginners' version of the manual. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @ali_m That's okay.