# Glossaries not printing out fully on first use any more

Tags: glossaries

I'm writing in a rather large document, closing to 90 pages soon in PDF format.
So far, glossaries have been working wonderfully, but now it seems to be a bit buggy after having so many entries (99 entries right now).

My two latest entries into glossaries were:

```
\newacronym{radius}{RADIUS}{Remote Authentication Dial-In User Services}
\newacronym{xml}{XML}{Extensible Markup Language}
```

None of these get printed out on the first use (when using `\gls` command), but all the earlier entries do. It's like glossaries can't handle that many entries and it breaks.

I would insert some example code, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: I doubt that this is an error with `glossaries`. I am sure `glossaries` can handle much more than 99 entries. You should provide us with more information!

Comment: Things to check: have you defined all your entries in the preamble? Has `makeindex`/`xindy` reported any errors or warnings? (Check the transcript file, which probably has the extension `.glg` or `.alg`.)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What information do you need?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot No, they are placed in a file called `glosario.tex`.
Transcript file says: `This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2015] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./report.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file report.glo....done (518 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries.......done (5098 comparisons).
Generating output file report.gls....done (293 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in report.gls.
Transcript written in report.glg.`

Comment: How do you load `glosario.tex`? (`\input` or `\loadglsentries`?)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot
with `\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{glosario}`

Comment: Are there any warnings in the `.log` file? (Search for lines containing `Package glossaries`.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Yes, `Package glossaries Warning: No language module detected for swedish.` and `Package glossaries Info: Writing glossary file report.glo on input line 75.` (line 75 is `\makeglossaries`)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm stumped. I think you'll have to [hack down to a MWE](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/hackingdown.html). I'll run some tests with a large number of entries to see if anything crops up.

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment, but just to confirm that `glossaries` doesn't have a problem with 100 entries, here's a test document that defines and uses 1000 sample entries (defined with `\newglossaryentry`) and 1000 sample abbreviations (defined with `\newacronym`). All 2000 entries are correctly displayed.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\newcount\myctr
\newcount\maxentries

\maxentries=1000\relax

\glssetexpandfield{name}
\glssetexpandfield{description}
\glssetexpandfield{sort}

\loop
 \newglossaryentry{sample\number\myctr}{name={sample\number\myctr},
  description={sample description \number\myctr}}
 \newacronym{sa\number\myctr}{short\number\myctr}{long\number\myctr}
 \advance\myctr by 1\relax
\ifnum\myctr<\maxentries
\repeat

\begin{document}
\myctr=0\relax

\loop
 \gls{sample\number\myctr}.
 \gls{sa\number\myctr}.\glspar
 \advance\myctr by 1\relax
\ifnum\myctr<\maxentries
\repeat

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

- You've already confirmed in the comments that all entries have been defined in the preamble, so we can discount document definitions as the problem.
- If the above test document works fine for you, then we can discount any possible issues with your distribution.
- [Edit] Another test: you mentioned that the problematic entries aren't showing the full form on first use. Have you used them in a `\section` or `\chapter`? If so and you have a table of contents, then [Glossaries and custom section headings broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198140) might be the cause.

The next step is unfortunately rather tedious, but only you can do it, and that's to create a MWE that demonstrates the problem. Either:

- [Build up](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/buildingup.html) a test file, starting with your problematic entries and the context in which you use them (for example, if you are using them within a command argument or an environment), or
- [Hack down](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/hackingdown.html).

Comment: The test document works fine.
Well, i do have chapters and sections where `\gls` is used in for example the title of a section, but those work fine. The problematic `\gls` entries which aren't showing the full form on first use are just in regular text. The only thing special i can see is that they're inside a `tabularx` environment.

EDIT: Well, that's it. I found the problem. Apparently `\gls` entries inside a `tabularx` environment doesn't show full form on first use. If i move it outside it works! How would one solve this problem?

Comment: @morxy49 See [glossaries: fail to expand in tabularx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94885/glossaries-fail-to-expand-in-tabularx)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the solution in that thread. I don't understand what is making it work in the answer provided.

Comment: @morxy49 David, who provided that answer, is the author of `tabularx`, so he's the better person to explain. Perhaps ask him in a comment to his answer. Did you try out his solution? It should work even though it seems a little obscure. As far as I can guess it suppresses `\glsunset` on the trial run of `tabularx`, which was the cause of the problem.

Comment: I had this same problem when I used a `\gls` acronym entry in a `\subsection` definition.  In hindsight this was not such a good idea as I did not want the acronym to appear in the section title.

Answer (score 1):

The command `\glsunsetall` stops `LateX` from printing the full form of any glossary. To stop this effect, find and comment/remove it anywhere it appears in your text.