# Macro for creating uppercase and lowercase label glossary entries with one command

Tags: glossaries, expansion, acronyms

I am using the glossaries package for acronym handling, and I have already written a large document with many entries all using lowercase labels. However, it turns out that when I use those acronyms in section and chapter headings, they end up in the page headers in uppercase format. As a result, the keys do not work any more, because `\acrshort{abc}` becomes `\acrshort{ABC}`.

So since I don't want all of those occurrences to end up in the glossary anyway, I thought the easiest way to deal with this is to define a new command that creates each glossary entry in both uppercase and lowercase, and then moves the uppercase version to a nonexistent secondary glossary.

So here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,BCOR=8mm,DIV=14,headsepline,twoside,chapterprefix=true,cleardoublepage=plain]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym, numberedsection=autolabel, section=section, nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\newacronymup}[4][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
        \newacronym{#2}{#3}{#4}%
        \newacronym{{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{#2}}}{#3}{#4}%
    }{%
        \newacronym[sort=#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
        \newacronym[sort=#1]{{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{#2}}}{#3}{#4}%
    }%
    \glsmoveentry{\MakeUppercase#2}{null}%
}%
\newacronymup[sorting123]{gasp}{GASP}{Global Atmospheric Sampling Program}
\newacronymup{sqp}{SQP}{Sequential Quadratic Programming}

Test
\gls{sqp}
\gls{gasp}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % acronyms
\end{document}
```

If I comment out the three lines with `\MakeUppercase` in them, everything works as expected. But I can't seem to figure out how to make the labels uppercase without breaking it. I always end up with an error along the lines of

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
```

If I just test the `\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{#2}` part, it also works, which is why I don't really know how to debug the problem further.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Imho you should better solve the problem with the header.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there a way to make a piece of text uppercase without affecting any acronyms within it?

Comment: See [Entries in Sectioning Titles, Headers, Captions and Contents](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:headtitle).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thank you, that does solve my problem!

Comment: @JulianHzg Okay, I'll write it up as a proper answer.

Comment: Actually, I think it may be a duplicate of [Glossaries and custom section headings broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198140).