# Proper practice with acronym entries in headers

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, glossaries, fancyhdr

When a sectioning starts with `\Glsentrylong{SomeEntry}`, I'm running into issue that the capitalization is not transferred to the header, while the sectioning is properly capitalized.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,section=paragraph]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*\glossaryname{}
\makeglossaries
\setglossarystyle{super}
\glstoctrue

\newacronym{ACR}{ACR}{acronym}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Some title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagestyle{mystyle} % if this is commented out, the default section formating is capitalizing the first letter appropriately

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{\Glsentrylong{ACR}}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I noticed the issue is with `fancyhdr`, as if the default `book.cls` header is used, the first letter of the section name in the header is properly capitalized.

Comment: Related: [Glossaries and custom section headings broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198140)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot the suggested `\Glsfmtlong` provided by `glossaries-extra` does not solve the above mentioned issue.

Comment: In which case add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot a MWE has been added. It seems the problem is coming from `fancyhdr` and the `\sectionmark` formatting, since with the default `book.cls` header the capitalization of the first letter of the section is obtained.

Answer (score 1):

The first letter uppercasing commands like `\Glsentrylong` use `\MakeTextUppercase` to convert the first letter to upper case, but this is counteracted by `\nouppercase` in the page style. A minor change to the `\section` in your MWE:

```
\section{\Glsentrylong{ACR} \MakeTextUppercase{s}ample}
```

illustrates this:

[image: image of page header: 1.1 acronym sample]

I think the only solution is to remove `\nouppercase` from the page style and prevent the `book` class from applying upper casing. I think it would be better to use a more flexible class (such as `memoir` or `scrbook`) but if you want to stick with `book`, here's a possibility.

Although you've redefined `\sectionmark` and `\chaptermark` to remove `\MakeUppercase`, from their definition, they are reset by the `book` page styles. If you add `\show` before and after the page style is set

```
\show\sectionmark
\show\chaptermark
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\show\sectionmark
\show\chaptermark
```

the transcript file will show this:

```
> \sectionmark=\long macro:
#1->\markright {\thesection .\ #1}.
l.36 \show\sectionmark

? 
> \chaptermark=\long macro:
#1->\markboth {\chaptername \ \thechapter .\ #1}{}.
l.37 \show\chaptermark

? 
> \sectionmark=macro:
#1->\markright {\MakeUppercase {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@ \thesection . \ \fi 
#1}}.
l.40 \show\sectionmark

? 
> \chaptermark=macro:
#1->\markboth {\MakeUppercase {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \@chapapp \ \thecha
pter . \ \fi #1}}{}.
l.41 \show\chaptermark
```

If you move the redefinition of these commands to after the page style is set and remove `\nouppercase` from the page style, then the heading will be in lower case except for the `\MakeTextUppercase` parts.

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}%
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}%
}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,section=paragraph]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*\glossaryname{}
\makeglossaries
\setglossarystyle{super}
\glstoctrue

\newacronym{ACR}{ACR}{acronym}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Some title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}%

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{\Glsentrylong{ACR} \MakeTextUppercase{s}ample}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: image of page header: 1.1 Acronym Sample]