# Glossaries in section headings without shortening after TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, acronyms

here is another question from my LateX project.
Currently I'm using the package glossaries to mange my acronyms. I use some acronyms in sectionheadings. Therefore the acronym is first discribed in the table of content. After that, the section heading in the document only includes the short form. 
My goal is, to have the section headings in full lengt. The TOC should not "count".
Here is my minimal code example to show the problem.
if you remove `\tableofcontents` the acronym in the section heading is as i would like it.
Also the \printglossaries is not working.

```
\documentclass[english, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{NMR}{NMR}{nuclear magnetic resonance spectroscopy}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoubleoddpage

\section{Data}
\subsection{\gls{NMR}}
In the Text, the \gls{NMR} entry should look like "NMR". In the section heading it should look like "Nuclear magnetic resonance spectroskopy".
\cleardoubleoddpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: See [Why shouldn't I use commands like \gls in \section, \chapter, \caption etc?](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#whynoglsinsection) and [Entries in Sectioning Titles, Headers, Captions and Contents](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:headtitle).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glossaries and custom section headings broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198140).

Comment: I saw the warning, but tried it without so I know that this is not intendet to do. 
I did not understand the manual completly to work around that problem. In the final work I disabled the hyperlink anyway so nested links are no problem. 
Using `\glsentryfull{NMR}`is not helping, because in the text, the `\gls{NMR}` is written in text and acronym again.
I tried to read the glossaries-extra but maybe my english is not good enought. The first use flag is the problem and there are some hints towards the `\glsxtrrestoremarkhook`to restore the first used flag after the table of contens?

Comment: Ok so to clear entries after the toc I can use \glsresetall
That fixes the Problem. If the acronym comes up in the Text before, i use the `\glsentryfull` or `\glsentrytext` for the section